# How to define Y and X variables in Firth's penalized logistic regression

Tags: r, logistic, modeling

1. I'm using Firth's penalized logistic regression in R with `logistf` package.
   Should the Y variable be defined as factor (L$Y = factor(L$Y) before running a model or not? Because the outcomes of the model were different when the Y variable was and was not defined as factor before running and the `stpPlr` package cannot run when I defined the Y variable as factor.
2. How to select the best model for the Firth's penalized logistic regression?
   Which package can I use for model selection and which value we use for comparing the models?